# simple-peer removeTrack/removeStream is destroying the peer instead of just removing the mediaStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, simple-peer

guys I am having a problem in which I am trying to create a project that is working on peer to peer connection, When I have a connection between two peers and I addStream, I can hear the audio and stuff that is okay, But when I want to remove the stream it basically removes the whole peer and The connection is dead so they are not communicating anymore but what I want is 
to only remove the audioStream not the whole communication. So when I add the stream again it will just add the audio stream.

```
        video.pause();
        video.removeAttribute('src'); // empty source
        jquery(video).remove();
        peer.removeStream(mediaStream);
```

Answer (score -2):

Hmm not pretty sure what u are trying to do, but for removing only the audio track u need to do something like this

```
peer.removeTrack(stream.getAudioTracks()[0], stream);
```

it's taking from the official docs